# BIRT report viewer - custom error reporting

Tags: java, eclipse, reporting-services, birt

We have several reports and several applications feeding the reports with data.
We use BIRT Report Viewer 2.3.2 to display the reports.

Thing is, when an application is unreachable the BIRT Report Viewer displays an error message box titled "Exception" with the exception header, the link to expand the stack trace, and two buttons, ok and cancel.

For these kind of exceptions i would like a friendlier message saying something like "Application X is reloading, please wait a few minutes and try again.", with no stack trace, and only one ok button.

The exception is: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager openConnection
SEVERE: Cannot open connection.
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: There is an error in get connection, The url cannot be null.

In any case i do not care what the exception happens to be, i want it logged in the log4j and a friendly message box displayed on the BIRT Report Viewer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Questions that show some attempt to solve the problem before asking for help are more likely to get an answer.  What have you tried?

Comment: well, since BIRT Report Viewer is a package we include in our application, it is hard to tweak. basically we call the url "/frameset" with the params and that is it.
then the exception arises and all happens out of our scope.

Comment: i tried adding a js to the report, but the report never gets to load and thus the js is never loaded. i also tried to modify the behavior through java reflexion, but the internal classes are a web of calls and it did not worked (plus it is a messy approach).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize the exception then 
Goto -->**\webcontent\birt\pages\dialog\ExceptionDialogFragment.jsp** of your war file and you can customize of your own message like 
**Sorry for the Inconvenience. Unexpected Error Occurred. Please contact administrator** 
by removing the **stack trace** provided in that **jsp** file.