# How to Customize Birt Report viewer Exception

Tags: java, report, birt

I am working on Birt Report. And i have noticed that after some time if i am not using/working on report and try to run the report then a "Exception" occurred like saying "The Viewing Session is not available or has expired".
The thing i want here is to customize this exception.

I have tried this solution ([BIRT report viewer - custom error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091701/birt-report-viewer-custom-error-reporting))!
but i am unable to customize the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably due to Tomcat session, which is different from web viewer session parameter you mentioned. You should try to set the timeout value you like in web.xml of the viewer, or in <tomcat_home>/conf/web.xml

```
<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

for further details click (https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/544335/)

Comment: Yes, I can here customize timeout session. So it might be helpful to delay expiration time and let user to browse reports in that specific time frame.